# Images not showing up in views with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I installed the Views Module and I am trying to display a picture in the content type(menu item with title and picture) but when I add the image field from the content type named 'menu item' to the view it is not showing up?  I dont understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a 'relationship' on the far right hand side of the views ui.  You have to select the image with the same machine readable name and link that to the image your are trying to display and hopefully itll work out.  This stumped me for like 3 or 4 hours. grrrrrr!